# I tried to remove punctuation in list but it has problem TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
text = df["column1"].tolist()
```

result

```
["\re","jungk+","tae"]
```

and Then I tried to remove punctuation

```
remove_punc = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in text]
```

and it appears that

```
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ca147a70ac4f> in <module>
----> 1 remove_punc = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in text]

<ipython-input-25-ca147a70ac4f> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 remove_punc = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in text]

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

p.s. My dataset is Thai language not English

Comment: `text` must not be the list you showed.

Comment: make sure you don't have `NaN` values in text

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with `text = ["\\re","jungk+","tae"]`

Comment: It seems like you have a float object in your df that is causing the error. Are you sure that text consists entirely of strings?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the commas from the string representation of a python list? Why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a float value in text. 
Try

```
remove_punc = [''.join(c for c in str(s) if c not in string.punctuation) for s in text]
```

This will convert the float value to a string. However this would remove the decimal point.